# Need Help In WebBrowser Control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        WebBrowser.Show()
        WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.carsonmap.com/hidalgo/login.cfm")
        WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").SetAttribute("value", "lrgvdc")
        WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PW").SetAttribute("value", WebBrowser.TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub
```

I need help with this code I keep getting an error saying Null Reference.

I got the idea from this Youtube Video check out to see what I am trying to accomplish.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EJXzWasTq4&list=PL42055376AE25291E&index=41
They used  two buttons to enter to the website I am trying to enter to a website By using one button any ideas why doesnt it work.

Comment: Which line throws the error? The one with `WebBrowser.Show()`?

Comment: It throws the error in webrowser.webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("UserName").SetAttribute("value", "lrgvdc")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `WebBrowser1.Navigate` - it just begins to load document, the document is not available right away.

You need to use [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to place your code that works on document's elements. E.g. something like

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  WebBrowser.Show()
  WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.carsonmap.com/hidalgo/login.cfm")
End Sub



Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

  WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").SetAttribute("value", "lrgvdc")
  WebBrowser.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PW").SetAttribute("value",    WebBrowser.TextBox2.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: But it does loads the document in the second form called webbrowser. I can manually input stuff into the website. But It wont do it automatic.

Comment: Your code executes faster that control loads the document. Document simple is not ready when you issue those commands

Comment: @user2270667 This is the correct answer, you have to wait for the document to completely finish loading before you can access it.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy Galanter that actually works. Is this what they were talking about instance.

Comment: @user2270667 no, the instance makes sense when control is created programmatically from a class. This is not the case.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses I am glad that many help me I developing a program learning little techniques back and forward from different tutorials on YouTube. I actually like this program that I am creating I have made one in Microsoft Access but I am trying to get away from it to more on its own. I found vb.net really useful.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great resource, were you should find a lot of help. Just don't forget to mark answers as accepted if solution works for yoou.

Comment: Hey Yuriy I have one more thing to ask for this question. I added it this to the code

Comment: webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Submit").InvokeMember("click")

Comment: this part didn't go through WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Proprec1_AccountNumber").SetAttribute("value", form2.TextBox2.Text) that didnt go through once it log in.

Comment: Could u please either update your question with new code, or better yet open a new one (since it's a new problem) and post updated code there - both working and not working part and description of the problem - because it's getting really hard to track it in the comments