# WebBrowser not Loading (VB 2008)

Tags: vb.net

Recently I've been trying to create a program to make account creation faster.

And, I've been having the same error.

I've even set up something to test if it's busy or not.

My code so far:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.gmail.com/")
    If WebBrowser1.IsBusy = False Then
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-signup")


    Else

    End If
```

By the way, I'm a noob at VB, and I just wanna learn more about it.

Error is Null Reference Error

Comment: You need to use DocumentCompleted event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067160/need-help-in-webbrowser-control-in-vb-net/18067226#18067226

Comment: And what is the error? Document is null?

Comment: What line is causing the error? What happens when you set a breakpoint on that line in the debugger?